# Using COM IAdviseSink interface to get clipboard changes

Tags: c++, uwp, com, windows-runtime, clipboard

I'm trying get id of a process which changes the content of a clipboard using implementation of a IAdviseSink interface. The application which id i try to detect is WinRT UWP. I have clipboard viewer and clipboard listner which are calls on WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD and WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE events. Inside this methods i call `::GetClipboardOwner()` and `::GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to figures out process id.

```
bool IsHwndWinContainer(HWND hwnd)
{
    wchar_t wszClassName[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    ::GetClassName(hwnd, wszClassName, _countof(wszClassName));

    return _wcsicmp(wszClassName, L"ApplicationFrameWindow") == 0;
}

HWND GetHwndWinRTApp(HWND winRTcontainer)
{
    return FindWindowEx(winRTcontainer, NULL, L"Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow", NULL);
}

//....

HWND hwndClipboardOwner = ::GetClipboardOwner();

if (!IsHwndWinContainer(hwndClipboardOwner))
{
    HWND realHwndProcess = GetHwndWinRTApp(hwndClipboardOwner);

    hwndClipboardOwner = realHwndProcess ? realHwndProcess : hwndClipboardOwner;
}

DWORD dwClipboardOwnerWindowProcessId = 0;
::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndClipboardOwner, &dwClipboardOwnerWindowProcessId);
```

The id i get is not the same as id of WinRT app i try to reserch. I know that UWP apps is containered and, i think, the reason in that. I also have dll with hooks on SetClipboardData() and GetClipboardData() and on OLE relatives OleSetClipboard() and OleGetClipboard(). And when i copy a text on this app there is only calls of OLE set and get methods.

After little reserch i found information about IAdviseSink interface and trying to implement it. All goes ok until call of `DAdvise()` on IDataObject object. This small demo of my attemps:

```
class MyAdviseSink : public IAdviseSink
{
    LONG _cRef = 0;

public:
    virtual void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDataChange(FORMATETC* pFormatetc, STGMEDIUM* pStgmed)
    {
        DWORD processId = GetCurrentProcessId();
        std::cout << processId;
    }

    virtual void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnClose() {}
    virtual void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnRename(IMoniker* pmk) {}
    virtual void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnSave() {}
    virtual void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnViewChange(DWORD dwAspect, LONG lindex) {}

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef()
    {
        return InterlockedIncrement(&_cRef);
    }


    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release()
    {
        ULONG ulRef = InterlockedDecrement(&_cRef);

        if (0 == ulRef)
        {
            delete this;
        }

        return ulRef;
    }


    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(
        REFIID riid, VOID** ppvInterface)
    {
        if (IID_IUnknown == riid)
        {
            AddRef();
            *ppvInterface = (IUnknown*)this;
        }
        else if (__uuidof(IAdviseSink) == riid)
        {
            AddRef();
            *ppvInterface = (IAdviseSink*)this;
        }
        else
        {
            *ppvInterface = NULL;
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
        }

        return S_OK;
    }
};


int main()
{
    HRESULT res = ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    MyAdviseSink* pAdviseSink = new MyAdviseSink();

    IDataObject* pDataObject;
    res = ::OleGetClipboard(&pDataObject);

    FORMATETC formatetc;
    ZeroMemory(&formatetc, sizeof(FORMATETC));

    formatetc.cfFormat = CF_UNICODETEXT;
    formatetc.tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;
        formatetc.dwAspect = DVASPECT_CONTENT;
        formatetc.lindex = -1;

    DWORD adviseCookie = 0;
    res = pDataObject->DAdvise(&formatetc, ADVF_PRIMEFIRST, pAdviseSink, &adviseCookie);

    MessageBox(NULL, L"Waiting clipboard changing...", L"Example", MB_OK);

    pDataObject->DUnadvise(adviseCookie);
    pDataObject->Release();
    delete pAdviseSink;

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

By debugging i get folowing result of `DAdvise()` call: `0x80040003: This implementation doesn't take advise.`. What i doing wrong? Or maybe exists any other approach to get notification of clipboard content changes with ability to get process id which made this changes.

Comment: OleInitialize is missing

Comment: Should i add call of `OleInitialize()` or replace call of `CoInitialize()`?

Comment: Replace call of CoInitialize(). OleInitialize() does same thing as CoInitialize() + some extra OLE initialization stuff... some of which is related to the clipboard. And of course, replace CoUninitialize() with OleUninitialize(). Online docs for OleInitialize() describes the extra stuff...